# How to capitalize a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

How can I convert a string to all capitals in Python 3.4?

for example, I want to convert:

```
string
```

to:

```
STRING
```

I have tried with the `.upper` method, but it returns:

```
"string".upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x0283E860>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need `()` after the method name to call the method. `"string".upper()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [string.upper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) method in Python 3.4

For example

```
>>> x = 'abcdef'
>>> x.upper()
>>> 'ABCDEF'
```

Or if you only need the first letter to be capitalized, you can use [string.capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) method like

```
>>> x = 'abcdef'
>>> x.capitalize()
>>> 'Abcdef'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the parentheses since `upper` is a method. It should be `"string".upper()`.
If you don't add the parentheses, it will return the function object instead of calling the function.