# I'm trying to camelCase four phrases

Tags: python, camelcasing

Super beginner to `Python` here. Here's my code so far:

```
def make_camel_case(word_string):
    word_list = word_string.split(’ ’)
    output = ’’
    for word in word_list:
        word_upper = word[0].upper()
        output = output+word_upper
    return(output)
def camel_case():
    phrase1 = ’purple people eater’
    phrase2 = ’i can\’t believe it\’s not butter’
    phrase3 = ’heinz 57 sauce’
    print(make_camel_case(phrase1))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase2))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase3))
camel_case()
```

And here is my desired output:

```
purplePeopleEater
iCan’tBelieveIt’sNotButter
heinz57Sauce
```

My primary error message is `invalid character in identifier in line 2`

After an edit my code runs properly, but outputs:

```
 PPE
 ICBINB
 H5S
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting only the first character to upper case in `word_upper` variable. To get the desired output you need to do 2 things.

1. Skip the 1st word of the sentence
2. Replace the first character of subsequent words with its uppercase and append it to output.
   to achieve that, you would have to change your loop and use `enumerate()` to get the word index from loop [(see here)](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) and then for later words replace the first character only.
   The code would be

```py
def make_camel_case(word_string):
    word_list = word_string.split(' ')
    output = ''
    for i,word in enumerate(word_list):
        if(i != 0):
          word_upper = word[0].upper()
          word = word_upper + word[1:]
        output = output + word
    return(output)
def camel_case():
    phrase1 = 'purple people eater'
    phrase2 = 'i can\'t believe it\'s not butter'
    phrase3 = 'heinz 57 sauce'
    print(make_camel_case(phrase1))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase2))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase3))
camel_case()
```

For a cleaner solution, use `str.capitalize()` function [(see here)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-capitalize-python/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20the%20capitalize(),string_name.) suggested by [@federico-baù.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903942/federico-ba%C3%B9) Then the function would become something like this,

```py
def make_camel_case(word_string):
    word_list = word_string.split(' ')
    output = ''
    for i,word in enumerate(word_list):
        if(i != 0):
          word = word.capitalize()
        output = output + word
    return(output)
```

Hope it clarified your question. Keep learning.

Answer (score 6):

Easy pease, just use the [capitalize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574191/how-to-capitalize-a-string-in-python) function:

```
def make_camel_case(word_string):
    word_list = word_string.split(' ')
    output = ''

    for word in word_list:
        word_upper = word.capitalize()
        output += word_upper
    return output
def camel_case():
    phrase1 = 'purple people eater'
    phrase2 = "i can't believe it’s not butter"
    phrase3 = 'heinz 57 sauce'
    print(make_camel_case(phrase1))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase2))
    print(make_camel_case(phrase3))
camel_case()
```

Answer (score 5):

The error caused on second line is cause by causing indvalid character ’. You should use single quotes ' ' or double quotes " " to split text by spaces.

Then you can simply do .upper() for each first letter of each word to make it uppercase and at the end, merge all the words into the desired string.

Comment: Thank you! Got that. The code is now running properly but I am getting an incorrect output which I edited into my post. Sorry for any formatting weirdness, just now getting used to Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you apply .upper() to a string, it outputs that string in uppercase. What you need to figure out is a way to make the first letter upper and then join the rest of the word with it into a new variable or a new list.
Something like this:
word _list = word_string.split(),
Then you create a new variable result = "" and cycle through the word_list with for loop and then you can take first letter an make it uppercase:  first_let = word[0].upper(), take the rest: rest = word[1:] and add the whole thing into the result: result += first_let+rest

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to split your words, you can use .capitalise() on every word in the list instead.